# CSS Not Rendering Properly in MVC 5.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, bootstrap-4

I am using MVC 5.2. I'm trying to implement some prewritten css from https://bootswatch.com/lumen/. I've downloaded the bootstrap file and renamed it to bootstrap-lumen.css. After placing it in my content folder, I updated the BundleConfig file as shown below: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f7IO.png)

When I run the app, I get a header that looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITjMR.png)

I am not seeing anything in the chrome dev tools that would explain this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well the sequence in which you wrote the css file in BundleConfig matters. Try the following.

Placing bootstrap-lumen.css below the site.css

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/Content/bootstrap-lumen.css"));
```

if that doesn't work try to remove site.css from the list and see the results

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-lumen.css"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that your bootstrap-lumen.css is based on bootstrap v 4.3.1.  Whereas the html in your layout is set up for bootstrap version 3.4.1.  So you will need to look at how navigation is done in bootstrap 4 in their [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) and make changes to the html in your _layout.cshtml accordingly.

Also since Bootswatch is based on bootstrap 4 you will need to update your bootstrap.js to the latest version which is currently v4.3.1 and also include popper.js in the bootstrap bundle.

Here is an example _Layout.cshtml file you could use to get started

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="./" class="navbar-brand">My application</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">                
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })                       
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        @Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", new { @class = "nav-link" })
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```